# URL with port validation objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

I want to validate url with port so i need regular expression to validate it.
Currently I am using this expression.

```
NSString *urlRegEx =@"(?i)(?:(?:https?|http):\\/\\/)?(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?";
```

but it is not validating sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

Let's take an URL:

> https://some.long.domain.with.subdomains.com:12345/otherpath?queryparam=queryvalue

Let's initialise NSURL with this string:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:theStringFromAbove];
```

If URL is invalid, the `url` variable will be nil. Otherwise, grab a port and check if it's what we need:

```
if (!url || [url port] != 12345) {
    NSLog(@"YOU SHALL NOT PASS");
}
```

Comment: what id my url contains ip for example
http://192.168.0.123:8081/service/service.asmx

Comment: what should i do if there is ip like in my above comment.

Comment: Read the documentation for `NSURL` class. the IP address will be accessible through `host` property of the object.